# Where is the documentation for the values() method of Enum?

Tags: java, enums

I declare an enum as :

```
enum Sex {MALE,FEMALE};
```

And then, iterate enum as shown below :

```
for(Sex v : Sex.values()){
    System.out.println(" values :"+ v);
}
```

I checked the Java API but can't find the values() method? I'm curious as to where this method comes from?

API link : 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html

Answer (score 204, accepted):

You can't see this method in javadoc because it's added by the compiler.

Documented in three places :

- [Enum Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), from The Java Tutorials

> The compiler automatically adds some special methods when it creates
>   an enum. For example, they have a static values method that returns an
>   array containing all of the values of the enum in the order they are
>   declared. This method is commonly used in combination with the
>   for-each construct to iterate over the values of an enum type.

- [`Enum.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) class
  (The special implicit `values` method is mentioned in description of `valueOf` method)

> All the constants of an enum type can be obtained by calling the implicit public static T[] values() method of that type.

- [Enum Types, Section 8.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9), [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html)

The `values` function simply list all values of the enumeration.

Comment: any specific reason for this? why it's not part of API?

Comment: Because using just the standard mechanism (without enum), you couldn't have this static method. The java specification had to be extended to allow those enums, that's why it must be added by the compiler.

Comment: Since Java 7 this has been added to the javadoc of java.lang.Enum, in the description of the static valuOf method.

Comment: @Catweazle Good observation. I give the link [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf).

Comment: @Catweazle Funny that it's not listed as its own method. I completely missed that!

Comment: Does calling "values()" create a new array, or does it re-use the same one?

Comment: @androiddeveloper it returns a new array (otherwise you might mess with the enum)

Comment: @DenysSéguret I see. Thank you. Do you know if it's written somewhere that this is what's supposed to be?

Comment: @androiddeveloper No but it's kind of implicit. It's said that it returns the array containing the values of the enumeration. As an array can't be constant in java, the only way to guarantee the array hasn't been changed (it might be on another thread) is to make a new one.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Sure an array can be constant. Just set it as "private static final", and inside a "static" block, initialize it. The values there can be modified, but this doesn't mean it should affect the enum itself, as the values aren't stored there. In any case, thank you.

Comment: The values can be modified, that's the point, so you can't share the array, hence you must give a different one at every access.

Answer (score 39):

The method is implicitly defined (i.e. generated by the compiler).

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2):

> In addition, if `E` is the name of an `enum` type, then that type has the following implicitly declared `static` methods:
>
> ```
> /**
> * Returns an array containing the constants of this enum 
> * type, in the order they're declared.  This method may be
> * used to iterate over the constants as follows:
> *
> *    for(E c : E.values())
> *        System.out.println(c);
> *
> * @return an array containing the constants of this enum 
> * type, in the order they're declared
> */
> public static E[] values();
>
> /**
> * Returns the enum constant of this type with the specified
> * name.
> * The string must match exactly an identifier used to declare
> * an enum constant in this type.  (Extraneous whitespace 
> * characters are not permitted.)
> * 
> * @return the enum constant with the specified name
> * @throws IllegalArgumentException if this enum type has no
> * constant with the specified name
> */
> public static E valueOf(String name);
> ```

Comment: `Added by the compiler` means there's no .java for this code or the code is generated by the compiler? I checked the [OpenJDK source code of Enum](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Enum.java) and there's no `values()`

Answer (score 13):

Run this

```
    for (Method m : sex.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        System.out.println(m);
    }
```

you will see

```
public static test.Sex test.Sex.valueOf(java.lang.String)
public static test.Sex[] test.Sex.values()
```

These are all public methods that "sex" class has. They are not in the source code, javac.exe added them

Notes:

1. never use sex as a class name, it's difficult to read your code, we use Sex in Java
2. when facing a Java puzzle like this one, I recommend to use a bytecode decompiler tool (I use Andrey Loskutov's bytecode outline Eclispe plugin). This will show all what's inside a class