# How to access a specific member in Java enum by Index value?

Tags: java, enums

I want to print the 2nd index value i.e SUMMER.

```
public class Filer
{
    public enum Season { WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, FALL }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(Season.values(2));//values don't take argument!!
    }
}
```

How can achieve it?

Comment: Season.SUMMER is the way to go. or iterate over the .values() result, and pick the second

Comment: I actually want to access it via index value.

Comment: `Season.values()[2]`...

Comment: so: look at what values() returns, and do a get of that index

Comment: You should avoid accessing `Enum` by index. They depend on their order in the code. If you do some refactoring like *"sort project alphabetical"* or later add some values to your enum without remembering your order-depend code, then you will break your code. Instead you may setup a `Map<Integer, Season>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code nearly works. Take a close look at the method signature of `Enum#values` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2)).

It is no method that accepts an argument, it returns the whole **array**. So you need to shift the access after the method as **array-access**:

```
Season.values()[2]
```

---

You should avoid accessing `Enum` by index. They **depend on their order** in the code. If you do some refactoring like *"sort project alphabetical"*:

```
public enum Season {
    FALL,    // 3 -> 0
    SPRING,  // 1 -> 1
    SUMMER,  // 2 -> 2
    WINTER   // 0 -> 3
}
```

or later add some values to your enum **without remembering** your **order-depend code**, then you will **break your code**. Instead you may setup a `Map<Integer, Season>`:

```
Map<Integer, Season> indexToSeason = new HashMap<>();
indexToSeason.put(0, Season.WINTER);
indexToSeason.put(1, Season.SPRING);
indexToSeason.put(2, Season.SUMMER);
indexToSeason.put(3, Season.FALL);
```

And then use that map for access:

```
public Season getSeasonByIndex(int index) {
    return indexToSeason.get(index);
}
```

Comment: That was really informative. But as you declared  Map<Integer, Season> indexToSeason = new HashMap<>();   shouldn't it be like   indexToSeason.put(0,Season.WINTER); and so on?

Comment: @Zabuza You should probably use `new HashMap<>(6)` because default initial capacity is 16 and you don't need that much. Default load factor is 0.75 so 6 is optimal for 4 items.

Comment: @TheKarlo95 Good point but I doubt that such micro-optimization will help here that much. In the worst case it only confuses a reader. Another alternative would be to use the very optimized factory methods `Map.of(...)` from **Java 9**.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the enum at a specific index try:

```
Season.values()[index]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can access them by typing the value that you want, e.g., `Season.WINTER`, calling `Season.valueOf("WINTER")`, or iterating over the `.values()` result, and pick what you want as @Stultuske stated.

If you search for `.values()` in [Class Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) you may not find it because this method is added by the compiler. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13659231/3927977).

If you need to actually access to the Enum via index value just use `Season.values()[someIndex]`, since `.values()` return an array `T[]`.

Find more information about Enums [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: copy pasting my comment and getting the name wrong? nice :p

Answer (score 2):

System.out.println(Season.values()[2]);