# Why I can not get .values() from Enum object class?

Tags: java, enums

I want to create universal method, for any enum object, that will check if enum has specified value name, but as `Enum` type object I am unnable to use method `values();`. Why?

Is there any way to get values from an `Enum` type object?

I need method like this to check if value from configuration is a valid string for `myEnum.valueOf(String);` because if given string will be wrong then it will throw an exception (and I do not want it).

I want my method to look like this:

```
public static Boolean enumContains(Enum en, String valueString){
    return toStringList(en.values()).contains(valueString.toUpperCase());
}
```

But there is no method `Enum.values()`. How to create this method correctly?

Comment: what is `Enum` in your example?

Comment: I want to make it universal, so I put just `Enum` as type of argument to match any `Enum` object to this method.

Comment: And `values` does only work for the `enum` type, e.g. `MyEnum.values()` but clearly not for a specific value of an `enum` like in your method...

Comment: ok, that can't work for any enum as explained by the others in the comment

Comment: Reflection would also be a workaround, but who wants to use reflection...`getDeclaredField("$VALUES");` or `Enum.class.getDeclaredMethod("values");` for the enum class

Comment: So how to create this method propetly without reducing it to single type of enum like MyEnum? I  want to create it for any enum object

Comment: @AKSW Your hack relies on a specific implementation of enums which may not be true for all Java implementations. And `getDeclaredField` is, in fact, using reflection.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I know, never said this is a solution nor did I provide it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Enum#values` is a method that is generated by the compiler, so you cannot use it at compile time unless you pass in a specific enum and not `Enum<?>`.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13659231/7294647

One solution would be to pass in a `Class<E extends Enum<E>>` instead and use `Class#getEnumConstants`:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> Boolean enumContains(Class<E> clazz, String valueString){
    return toStringList(clazz.getEnumConstants()).contains(valueString.toUpperCase());
}
```

If you have an enum named `MyEnum`, then you can simply pass in `MyEnum.class` as the first argument.