# Map enum to another enum with less amount of code in java

Tags: java, enums, code-duplication

I have two enum classes one is external and the other is internal.

```
public enum ExternalEnum
{
  EXTERNAL_CAR, EXTERNAL_VAN, EXTERNAL_BUS
}
```

---

```
public enum InternalEnum
{
  CAR, VAN, BUS
}
```

I need to map internal to external and external to internal. So I have done the following,

```
public class EnumMapper
{
  public ExternalEnum toExternal(InternalEnum internalEnum)
  {
    switch (internalEnum)
    {
    case BUS:
      return ExternalEnum.EXTERNAL_BUS;
    case CAR:
      return ExternalEnum.EXTERNAL_CAR;
    case VAN:
      return ExternalEnum.EXTERNAL_VAN;
    }
    return null;
  }

  public InternalEnum toInternal(ExternalEnum externalEnum)
  {
    switch (externalEnum)
    {
    case EXTERNAL_BUS:
      return InternalEnum.BUS;
    case EXTERNAL_CAR:
      return InternalEnum.CAR;
    case EXTERNAL_VAN:
      return InternalEnum.VAN;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

So same kind of mapping is repeating in two methods. Isn't there a good approach to achieve this using less amount of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using BiMap with less amount of code.

```
import com.google.common.collect.EnumBiMap;

public class EnumBiMapMapper
{
  private EnumBiMap<InternalEnum, ExternalEnum> enumEnumBiMap = EnumBiMap.create(InternalEnum.class, ExternalEnum.class);

  public EnumBiMapMapper()
  {
    enumEnumBiMap.put(InternalEnum.BUS, ExternalEnum.EXTERNAL_BUS);
    enumEnumBiMap.put(InternalEnum.CAR, ExternalEnum.EXTERNAL_CAR);
    enumEnumBiMap.put(InternalEnum.VAN, ExternalEnum.EXTERNAL_VAN);
  }

  public ExternalEnum toExternal(InternalEnum internalEnum)
  {
    return enumEnumBiMap.get(internalEnum);
  }

  public InternalEnum toInternal(ExternalEnum externalEnum)
  {
    return enumEnumBiMap.inverse().get(externalEnum);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
InternalEnum.values()[ externalEnum.ordinal() ]
```

## Details

Assuming the equivalent enum objects are declared in the same order, we can retrieve one enum object from the other by accessing the array of all enum objects returned from a call to the implicit `public static T[] values()` method (see [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13659217/642706)) and access by zero-based index number retrieved from the misnamed [`Enum#ordinal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()) method.

For example, `InternalEnum.values()` returns an array of all the enum objects in the order in which they were declared. Then we use array accessor `[…]` to retrieve the object matching the index number of its mate in the other enum.

```
InternalEnum internalEnum = InternalEnum.values()[ externalEnum.ordinal() ] ;
```

And vice versa:

```
ExternalEnum externalEnum = ExternalEnum.values()[ internalEnum.ordinal() ] ;
```

Here is example usage. Bonus tip: In Java 16+, we can declare an enum locally — see [*JEP 395: Records*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

```java
enum ExternalEnum { EXTERNAL_CAR, EXTERNAL_VAN, EXTERNAL_BUS }
enum InternalEnum { CAR, VAN, BUS }

System.out.println(
        InternalEnum.values()[ ExternalEnum.EXTERNAL_VAN.ordinal() ]
);

System.out.println(
        ExternalEnum.values()[ InternalEnum.VAN.ordinal() ]
);
```

> VAN
>
> EXTERNAL_VAN

Answer (score 1):

The answer from **Basil Bourque** is good, but I do not like to use `ordinal()` because you can easily rotate the `enum` constants and business logic will be broken.

You did almost correct, just remember, that `enum` constant is a plain old java `class` instance and it can be expanded with additional functionality. Therefore it's better to hide all mapper logic inside an `enum`.

```java
public enum ExternalEnum {
    EXTERNAL_CAR,
    EXTERNAL_VAN,
    EXTERNAL_BUS
}

public enum InternalEnum {
    CAR(ExternalEnum.EXTERNAL_CAR),
    VAN(ExternalEnum.EXTERNAL_VAN),
    BUS(ExternalEnum.EXTERNAL_BUS);

    private final ExternalEnum externalEnum;

    InternalEnum(ExternalEnum externalEnum) {
        this.externalEnum = externalEnum;
    }

    public ExternalEnum toExternal() {
        return externalEnum;
    }

    public static Optional<InternalEnum> parseExternal(ExternalEnum externalEnum) {
        for (InternalEnum internalEnum : values())
            if (internalEnum.externalEnum == externalEnum)
                return Optional.of(internalEnum);
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

**Demo**

```java
ExternalEnum externalEnum = ExternalEnum.EXTERNAL_CAR;
Optional<InternalEnum> optInternalEnum = InternalEnum.parseExternal(externalEnum);

System.out.println(externalEnum);
System.out.println(optInternalEnum.orElse(null));
System.out.println(optInternalEnum.map(InternalEnum::toExternal).orElse(null));
```

---

An alternative is to have only a `Mapper`

```java
public final class EnumMapper {
    
    private final Map<ExternalEnum, InternalEnum> MAP_EXT_INT = Map.of(
            ExternalEnum.EXTERNAL_CAR, InternalEnum.CAR,
            ExternalEnum.EXTERNAL_VAN, InternalEnum.VAN,
            ExternalEnum.EXTERNAL_BUS, InternalEnum.BUS);
            
    private final Map<InternalEnum, ExternalEnum> MAP_INT_EXT = Map.of(
            InternalEnum.CAR, ExternalEnum.EXTERNAL_CAR,
            InternalEnum.VAN, ExternalEnum.EXTERNAL_VAN,
            InternalEnum.BUS, ExternalEnum.EXTERNAL_BUS);
            
    public static ExternalEnum toExternal(InternalEnum internalEnum) {
        return MAP_INT_EXT.get(internalEnum);
    }
    
    public InternalEnum toInternal(ExternalEnum externalEnum) {
        return MAP_EXT_INT.get(externalEnum);
    }
    
    private EnumMapper() {}
}

public enum ExternalEnum {
    EXTERNAL_CAR,
    EXTERNAL_VAN,
    EXTERNAL_BUS
}

public enum InternalEnum {
    CAR,
    VAN,
    BUS;
}
```

Comment: oleg.cherednik, Is there a way to handle this by keeping the mapping in java data structure?

Comment: @abo you mean in `Mapper` class? `enum` is a java data structure as well.

Comment: oleg.cherednik, I mean like holding mapping in a map as key value pairs and get it when needed.